# Родительный падеж имени Ариша

Tags: орфография, склонение

Как правильно писать в родительном падеже: Аришы или Ариши?

Answer (score 2):

И. п. [Ари́ша](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0)
**Р. п. Ари́ши**
Д. п. Ари́ше
В. п. Ари́шу
Т. п. Ари́шей и Ари́шею
П. п. Ари́ше

В сочетаниях «жи» и «ши» после шипящих согласных всегда пишется буква «и».
В данном правиле исключений нет. Буква "ы" может быть использована после "ш" или "ж" только в именах собственных (например, город Шымкент в Казахстане).

*Эта нерешительность и испуг **Ариши** забавляли Гордея Евстратыча, и он, разглаживая свою подстриженную бороду, сделал по направлению к невестке несколько нерешительных шагов и даже протянул вперед руки* (Д. Мамин-Сибиряк. Золото).

Answer (score 0):

> ЖИ, ШИ пишутся с И

Это правило заучивают в школе как стихотворение.